# Gems upgrade error with due to looksee

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.2

When I upgraded my ruby gems, the following error appeared. It seems like this is related to some [bug](https://github.com/oggy/looksee/issues/15), but I I am not sure about the detail. How can I fix it?

> $ sudo gem update --system
>   Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/looksee-1.0.3.gemspec]: Illformed requirement   ["# 0.3.0"]
>   Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/looksee-1.0.3.gemspec]: Illformed requirement   ["# 0.3.0"]
>   Latest version currently installed. Aborting.

I uninstalled looksee-1.0.2, and I further tried to uninstall looksee, but I cannot:

> $ sudo gem uninstall looksee
>   Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/looksee-1.0.3.gemspec]: Illformed requirement   ["# 0.3.0"]
>   Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/looksee-1.0.3.gemspec]: Illformed requirement   ["# 0.3.0"]
>   INFO:  gem "looksee" is not installed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I can give you some tips on how to solve this.

1. Updating rubygems can break stuff. Recently I did `gem update --system` after about 6 months of not doing any Ruby and everything stopped working.
2. Ruby 1.9.1 is not really good, 1.9.2 is way less buggy
3. I recommend you take a look at `RVM` or `rbenv`, which will make these things easy

With RVM, you can easily do something like

```
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
rvm gemset empty
gem install bundler
cd your/project
bundle install
```

if things stop working, you can just do

```
rvm implode
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

and then start again, which is way faster than trying to fix bug after big updates.

I know this isn't the advice you were looking for, but it solves most gem related problems

Comment: Thanks for the nice advice. I am considering it.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, same gem looksee.  I did an rvm gemset empty, but still get the error.  I am reluctant to totally wipe rvm since I have 2 dozen gemsets and rvm wrappers defined. Is this a gem maintainers bug? George Ogata?